# Using tensorflow layers, model not trained

Tags: python, tensorflow, layer

I used keras on top of Theano before, and now want to write code in tensorflow style which is new to me. I tried writing a very simple model (which I implemented on keras and it worked), but the training process does not seem to work. The model always makes the same predictions no matter how many epochs I go trough, which shows the model is not updated in training process at all. I think I must have misunderstood something and made a stupid mistake, but cannot find where it is.

I am sure the input data and labels are correct, because I used them before. Input data training_input[0] and training_input[1] are 2D numpy arrays, respectively. Labels are one-hot with 4 dimensions.

```
def model_1(features, labels):
    hl_input = features['hl_input']
    bd_input = features['bd_input']
    encoder = tf.concat([hl_input, bd_input], axis=1)

    encoder = tf.layers.dense(encoder, 128, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    decoder = tf.layers.dense(encoder, 64)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(decoder, 4, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    predictions = tf.argmax(logits, 1, name="predictions")

    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=labels, logits=logits)
    train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(loss, tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(), optimizer='Adam',
                                           learning_rate=0.1)
    predictions = {"classes": predictions, "probabilities": logits}

    return predictions, loss, train_op
... ...
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(model_fn=model_1)
classifier.fit(x={'hl_input':training_input[0], 'bd_input':training_input[1]}, y=training_labels, batch_size=batch_size, steps=steps)
```

Comment: OK finally I found my problem. I used numpy array as one-hot vectors instead of tensors. So I need to add a line `labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.int32)`. Hopefully displaying my mistake can help others.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying `softmax` activation on the final layer twice. The `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy` function applies `softmax` internally, so remove the activation on the `logits` by setting `activation=None`.

Comment: Thanks that is truly an error and I corrected it. However it is not the reason why the model does not work at all. After the correction it still has the problem. I also printed out the predictions, and for any input, the output (logits) is exactly the same. For some reason, either the input data is not iterated properly or the model is radically biased. I will look into it.

Comment: I can only find a bug in the code being displayed there. Logits was passed as input, i can't guess its type as the problem.